# How to calculate the slope between touch point and UIImageView center

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How to calculate the slope between touch point and UIImageView center?

I tried a lot of codes, one of them is this:

```
CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:[myImage superview]];
double tx = myImage.center.x - translation.x;
double ty = myImage.center.y - translation.y;
double t_length = sqrt((tx*tx) + (ty*ty));
double a = cos(ty / t_length);
```

It is not giving a right angle, so please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atan2(y, x)` returns the angle between the line from `(0, 0)` to `(x, y)` and the positive
x-axis, so you probably need

```
double angle = atan2(myImage.center.y - translation.y, myImage.center.x - translation.x);
```

The return value is in radians, between -Pi and Pi. Note that the "y-value" comes first!

Comment: This code gives an angle between 35 and 75 only, whats the matter?

Comment: @phplover: atan2 returns a value between -Pi and Pi. If you convert that to degrees it is between -180 and 180. Perhaps you can show some input values where the result is not as expected.

Comment: Yes I know that I have to convert radians to degrees, and I did, but it is not showing a rational value.

Comment: @phplover: What do you mean by "not showing rational value"? Please show some input values where the computed angle is not as you expect. Otherwise it is difficult to help.

Comment: @phplover: `atan2(p2.y-p1.y, p2.x-p1.x)` calculates the angle of the line from `p1` to `p2`, and that is how I understood your question. I would like to help, but *"it's not rotating myImage correctly"* is a fairly bad problem description ...

Answer (score 0):

For this question, you want to think about which point you want the slope relative to. Actually, the magnitude of the slope will be the same but the signs would change. For example if the situation is like the image below:[image]

then you would calculate your slope using:

```
CGPoint myImageCenter = myUIImage.center;
CGPoint myClickedPoint =[gesture translationInView:[myImage superview]];
double slope = (myImageCenter.y - myClickedPoint.y) / ((myImageCenter.x - myClickedPoint.x))
```

This slope is the slope of the line, but be sure to think about touches that may happen in the top right corner, exactly above or below and exactly on the same horizontal plane as the center.